# Can you convert a .sh file to a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, converters, sh

I need to convert a .sh file to a .bat file so that it can run on windows I was wondering if there is a way to do so?
Here is the code i want to convert:

```
export ANDROID_SDK=C:\Users\Spencer Von Der Ohe\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
#
#
export HERE=${PWD}
export DALVIK_SDK=$HERE/../../
export JAVAFX_APP_DIR=$HERE/javafx/build/libs
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$PATH
export WORKDIR=$HERE/android
export PACKAGE="org.javafxports.helloworld"
export NAME="HelloAndroid"
./gradlew --info createProject -PDEBUG -PDIR=$WORKDIR -PPACKAGE=$PACKAGE -PNAME=$NAME  \
-PANDROID_SDK=$ANDROID_SDK -PJFX_SDK=$DALVIK_SDK -PJFX_APP=$JAVAFX_APP_DIR -PJFX_MAIN=$PACKAGE.$NAME
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not automatically but I suppose one can rewrite it as a `.bat` file manually. I'm not sure whether `.bat` has the same capabilities as `.sh`.

Comment: yap. read the code, understand what it does, and produce the same batch code.

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting it in a comment. And remember to indent the text 4 spaces to get syntax highlighting.

Comment: this is off-topic since the OP didn't show any research and the places where he/she was stuck

Answer (score 18, accepted):

your original .sh file just (1) sets some environment variables using the `export` command  and then (2) invokes an executable.

It should be pretty straightforward to translate it to `.BAT`.

1. Read `HELP SET`
2. change all the `export` commands to `SET`
3. change all references of `$variable` to `%VARIABLE%`
4. change `${PWD}` to `%CD%`
5. read `HELP SETLOCAL`
6. add `setlocal` as first line of the bat file
7. (optional) add `endlocal` as last line of the bat file
8. (suggestion for testing) insert `ECHO` in front of the command invocation

Comment: where is $HOME in the OP question?